# IE11 not remembering jsessionid on close & open browser from Tomcat 8.5.x onwards

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, internet-explorer-11

When i run my spring application in tomcat 8.5.x, after successful login and close (exit) the internet explorer without logout and open again the IE browser and give the same url address the application is not going to home page. The jsessionId is taking newly and it is opening login page.

This is not happening in 8.0.36 and other older versions.

Comment: can any one using Tomcat 8.5.3